# Why AudioManager.isStreamMuted isn't available?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I'm using android AudioManager to mute and unmute streams like STREAM_SYSTEM and STREAM_NOTIFICATION, muting is straightforward calling [setStreamMute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamMute%28int,%20boolean%29) but I'm unable to find an isStreamMuted method.

Looking inside source code I can see [it exists](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/media/AudioManager.java/#AudioManager.isStreamMute%28int%29) so the question is 'how can check if a stream is muted?

I'm working on Android 4.0.4

Comment: Nice question. looking for same. did you find answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unpleasant answer is that stream mute operates on a per-process basis. So you can safely store the mute state in a static variable somewhere, appropriately wrapped, and track mute state yourself. Speaking from bitter experience. Sometimes you do what you have to do. Why did they do that? That's a more difficult question....

Answer (score 8):

Reflections are your friend.  This worked for me.

```
try {
    Method m = AudioManager.class.getMethod("isStreamMute", int.class);
    isMuted = (Boolean) m.invoke(am, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Update: The method `public boolean isStreamMute (int streamType)` is now accessible in API 23 without using reflection.

Comment: thanks very mush & very very very small correction isMuted = (Boolean) m.invoke(am, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

Comment: Fixed in answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They stripped the method out of android.jar by using hide:

```
/**
 * get stream mute state.
 *
 * @hide
 */
public boolean isStreamMute(int streamType) {
```